# ¿Es posible crear una imagen en python a partir de una matriz que no es rectangular?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Para un proyecto de la universidad tengo que representar una señal que es cuasi-periodica. La idea es representar cada "periodo" en una fila de la imagen, pero al ser unos periodos mas largos que otros la matriz resultante no es rectangular, es decir, en vez de tener algo como esto [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]] tengo esto: [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5],[6, 7, 8, 9]]

Con matrices cuadradas existe plt.imshow() o similares, pero para mostrar una matriz que no es cuadrada existe alguna manera?

No me vale rellenar con ceros cada fila hasta que todas sean de la misma longitud porque entonces estaría introduciendo muestras falsas en la señal. La idea es que los pixeles vacíos se representen en negro o blanco para mostrar en la imagen que esos pixeles no son parte de la señal.

Answer (score 1):

Para que `plt.imshow()` admita una matriz, ésta debe tener el mismo número de elementos en cada fila. Por tanto no queda más remedio que rellenar los que faltan.

Pero rellenarlos con un número (sea cero o cualquier otro), como tú mismo dices, no es apropiado pues falsea los datos. Creo que la solución sería rellenar los que faltan con `NaN`. Ese es un valor especial de los flotantes que representa "No es un número" y por tanto es perfecto para señalar que esos datos faltan. Además, matplotlib no pintará nada en los datos que son NaN.

Para rellenar con NaN los datos faltantes puedes hacer uso de `zip_longest` de la biblioteca `itertools`. Esta función, si la llamas de la forma apropiada que luego veremos, irá iterando en paralelo por todas las filas, y devolviendo en cada iteración una tupla con un elemento de cada una de las filas. Dicho de otro modo, devuelve "columnas" de tu matriz. Y cuando una fila se termina, empieza a rellenar lo que falta con el valor que tú le des.

Por tanto:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import zip_longest

matriz = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5],[6, 7, 8, 9]]
rellenada = np.array(list(zip_longest(*matriz, fillvalue=np.nan))).T
```

Fíjate como, una vez aplicado el "truco" de `zip_longest` tendremos un iterable de columnas, que es lo que devuelve esa función. Lo convertimos a lista con `list()` y pasamos el resultado a `np.array()` que creará una matriz, ahora sí perfectamente rectangular y con NaN en los lugares que antes estaban vacios. El problema es que esa matriz, al ser construida a partir de las columnas, estará "girada". Por eso finalmente aplicamos el operador `.T` para obtener su traspuesta.

En este caso sale la siguiente matriz:

```
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3., nan],
       [ 4.,  5., nan, nan],
       [ 6.,  7.,  8.,  9.]])
```

donde podemos observar los valores que originalmente tenía la matriz de entrada, junto con los `nan` de relleno.

Ahora sí podemos pasar esa matriz a `plt.imshow()` que no pintará nada en donde haya nan:

```
plt.imshow(rellenada)
```

[image: Imagen resultado]

### Ampliación

Si quieres que los datos faltantes salgan en otro color, basta especificar a Matplotlib un color de fondo diferente para la gráfica, puesto que los nan no los pinta y por tanto saldrán del color del fondo.

Por ejemplo, mapa de colores azules para los datos y un rosa salmón para los que no están:

```
plt.imshow(rellenada, cmap="Blues")
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_facecolor('xkcd:salmon')
```

[image: Otro ejemplo]